# The ref- and cv-stripping property of `auto`.

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, decltype

I learned that declaring a variable using auto in this way

```
auto var = expr;
```

basically is like taking the type of `expr` and stripping &/&&-references and all top-level constness and volatileness from it. Does this mean that the above line is *exactly* equivalent to the following?

```
std::remove_cv<std::remove_ref<decltype(expr)>::type>::type var = expr;
```

Comment: You may like the upcoming `decltype(auto)` in C++14 :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Could you provide more details, please?

Comment: It's the type deduction of `auto` combined with the reference semantics of `decltype` - as in `decltype(auto) x = foo();`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, that is not true. `auto var = expr;` is more like passing `expr` by value.

```
int x[1];
auto y = x;
```

This makes `y` a `int*`.

Mostly `auto x = expr;` behaves like template type deduction:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T);
int x[1];
f(x); // deduces T as int*
```

It is more like `std::decay<decltype(expr)> var = expr;`.

Comment: So is `std::decay<decltype(expr)>::type var = expr;` *exactly* equivalent to `auto var = expr`?

Comment: Not exactly. This is C++: it has the rule that the only rule without exceptions is this one. `auto x = []{};` makes a lambda type, but lambdas cannot be used in `decltype`.